# Creating a shape using a :before pseudo element in CSS

Tags: html, css

So I've got some `h3` tags that I want to prepend with a simple red box.  I would have thought something like

```
h3:before {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #9B191D;
}
```

But I actually also have to add a

```
position: absolute
```

in order to get a shape to show up, and in that case the following text becomes obscured.  So currently I'm doing the following, and I really don't like it

```
h3:before {
    background: #9B191D;
    position: relative;
    content: "..";
    color: #9b191d;
}
```

but it works.  Does anyone know how I can get a shape with given dimensions to show up *without* using `position:absolute`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, a pseudo element's `display` is `inline`. You can't set the `width`/`height` of a strictly inline-level element, therefore you should change the `display` to `inline-block`.

In doing so, you don't have to resort to absolute positioning in order to change the dimensions of the element.

```css
h3:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #9B191D;
}
```

```html
<h3>Some header</h3>
```